# Securing network communication in p2p system intended for LAN

Tags: security, network-programming

I'm working on p2p application intended for LAN. Users are supposed to connect directly to each other without any server. At the moment application works on Linux, but I think about porting it on Windows and Android.

At the moment I simply establish unencrypted TCP connection, which is fine in early development stage. Later I'd like to use secure channels and here's my question -  how can I establish secure connection (assuring confidence and authentication like TLS) in distributed, p2p solution for LAN? Is it even possible?

I cannot use TLS, because I will not have any central server working as certificate authority. Moreover my LAN have no internet connection. Anonymous TLS is partial solution (will it work on Android?).

Because users will be in the same LAN, I may assume they will be e.g. sitting next to. Therefore they may "physically" authenticate themselves and e.g. share key or part of key (PIN)?

Comment: Q: "how can I establish secure connection" - A: " they may "physically" authenticate themselves" - If you have a secure way of key exchange you can use any encryption scheme/algorithm you like and have available. - I feel like you have some important details missing in your question.

Comment: Which goals do you want to achieve in terms of entity authentication and key integrity and freshness and (explicit?) key authentication and forward secrecy? If you think TLS (with client authentication) does not work for you, you will want to look at more generic key establishment and authentication protocols. I would nevertheless strongly discourage you from baking your own protocol.

Comment: Re: TLS vs. Android - http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned

Comment: @HannoBinder this is only partly true. Given one major security assumption in protocol design is that "Any adversary is able to obtain the value of the session key used in any sufficiently old previous run of the protocol" (meaning the actual payload) it is absolutely vital NOT to used a pre-shared secrets directly as encryption key for an encryption scheme. Even more, doing so would undermine any other security goals of the protocol and expose the participants to numerous attacks (replay etc). This can only be prevented using a sound key establishment protocol.

Comment: One more comment on TLS: TLS does not need a "live" server working as central certificate authority. Indeed a certificate and signing authority may be needed, such that the certificates can serve as pre-shared secrets, but from the perspective of the protocol this is not part of it. In larger environments certificate revocation may be a point to address nevertheless.